# convert fetch get to axios method

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

Im currently struggling to convert a fetch get request to an axios get request.

Here is my fetch request:

```
window.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Origin': window.location.origin,
    },
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
})
```

I am trying to convert it to axios, but am struggling to find corresponding attributes for cache and credentials. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caching:

```
const config = {
 headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
 }
};

const { data } = await axios.get(url, config);
```

for credentials, check the attribute [withCredentials](https://github.com/axios/axios). By default, it is set to false.